# Prove that the locus of the midpoints of the chord of the circle $x^2+y^2-2x+2y-2=0$ parallel to the line $y=x+5$

Tags: conic-sections

Prove that the locus of the midpoints of the chord of the circle $x^2+y^2-2x+2y-2=0$ parallel to the line $y=x+5$ is the line which passes through (0,0)

Let the point be (h,k)

$$T=S_1$$
$$xx_1+yy_1+g(x+x_1)+f(y+y_1)-c=x_1^2+y_1^2+2gx_1+2fy_1-c$$ where $(x_1,y_1)$ are the given midpoints of the chord.
$$hx+ky+(-1)(x+h)+(1)(y+k)-2=h^2+k^2-2h+2k-2$$

We only have to deal with terms containing x and y 
$$x(h-1)+y(k+1)+\lambda=0$$
Since it is parallel to $x-y+5=0$
$$h-1=1$$ and $$k+1=-1$$

$h=2$ and $k=-2$

What is going wrong?

Comment: Note that no calculation is needed. The centre lies on the line $x+y=0$ and the chords are all perpendicular to that line, so it passes through their midpoints.

Comment: @almagest I don’t follow. How can the center lie on a single line, since it passes through infinite lines? How did you arrive at $x+y=0$? And what’s wrong with what I did?

Comment: It is a single circle, so it has a single centre!

Comment: @almagest a single center from which infinite lines can pass

Comment: but only one perpendicular to $y=x+5$.

Comment: Incidentally, I have no idea what you did. Presumably you are taking $(h,k)$ to be the midpoint of a chord, but what is the lhs of the equation following $T=S_1$ supposed to be? And what are $T,S_1$?

Comment: Okay, forgive me for thinking it was standard. I will add it

Answer (score 0):

It should be slope of two lines be same.
$$m=-\frac{h-1}{k+1}=1$$
Hence $-h+1=k+1$
Hence locus is $ x+y=0$

Comment: Yes, (2,-2) also satisfies the locus. This doesn’t explain why h,k=(0,0)

Comment: Locus always have infinite point on it else it is not a locus it is only a fixed point.